# From YAML, list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, yaml

I am trying to pass some variable from a YAML file to a python script.
My YAML file is a nested dictionary with a list as value for specific key

```
---
source:
  address:
    - 10.0.0.1
    - 10.0.0.2
    - 172.16.0.1
  mask:
    - 255.255.255.255
    - 255.255.255.255
    - 255.255.255.0
```

I am trying to loop through the lists and print each value of the list

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml, sys

inventory = yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))

def function():
    for i,j in ['source']['address'],['source']['mask']:
        if inventory['source']['mask'] == '255.255.255.255':
            print('object-group network H-{}-32'.format(i))

function()
```

However I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thanks

Comment: `for i,j in ['source']['address'],['source']['mask']` is not valid python...

Answer (score 1):

`['source']['address']` tries to index the one-element list `['source']` with the index `'address'`, which does not make any sense for Python lists (and hence the error you are getting).

You probably want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml, sys

def function(inventory):
    source = inventory['source']
    for address, mask in zip(source['address'], source['mask']):
        if mask == '255.255.255.255':
            print('object-group network H-{}-32'.format(address))

inventory = yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'))
function(inventory)
```